# Why doesn't love2d use my custom-defined pairs metamethod?

Tags: lua, love2d, metatable, meta-method

I have the following code in the file main.lua:

```
local table = {data={a=1,b=2,c=3}}
setmetatable(table, table)

function table:__pairs()
    return pairs(self.data)
end

function table:__tostring()
    return "a table"
end

print(table)

for e in pairs(table) do
    print(e)
end
```

When I run `lua main.lua` I get the output

```
a table
a
b
c
```

When I run `love ~/path/to/project` I get the output

```
a table
__tostring
data
__pairs
```

Why does love use other metamethods correctly, but not pairs?

I have LOVE 11.3 (Mysterious Mysteries) and Lua 5.3.5

Comment: `__pairs` was introduced in Lua 5.2.  Are you sure LOVE uses Lua 5.3?  What is the variable `_VERSION` in LOVE?

Comment: Lua 5.1; that would explain it. Thank you, this should be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Although, is there anyway to change which version of Lua LOVE uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Love2D uses LuaJIT as its default interpreter, which is fixed to Lua 5.1. And while you can rebuild Love2D for the standard Lua 5.1 interpreter, making it use modern versions of the standard Lua interpreter would require substantial code hacking, since 5.2+ aren't backwards compatible.

And Lua 5.1 doesn't have the `pairs` metamethod.